# Resolution and Magnification

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I'm not able to comprehend the following paragraph in my textbook:

> There is a likelihood of confusion between resolution and
>   magnification, and similarly between the role of a telescope and a
>   microscope to deal with these parameters. A telescope produces images
>   of far objects nearer to our eye. Therefore objects which are not resolved
>   at far distance, can be resolved by looking at them through a telescope.
>   A microscope, on the other hand, magnifies objects (which are near to
>   us) and produces their larger image. We may be looking at two stars or
>   two satellites of a far-away planet, or we may be looking at different
>   regions of a living cell. In this context, it is good to remember that a
>   telescope resolves whereas a microscope magnifies.

**Why?**
Please explain.

Does a telescope not make small objects larger to see?
And does a microscope not resolve two objects (say 2 microscopic cells)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding microscopes, the image is often enlarged but the resolution is still poor, because the image is blurred, because point objects are seen as fuzzy discs surrounded by diffraction rings(Airy disks). So magnification and resolution are different things. Regarding telescopes, a telescopes does magnify and can be good at resolution too. I suspect that the author states that telescopes resolve because we are usually interested not in the magnification, but in the resolution, the capacity so separate two stars that will not look larger (as they are practically points in apparent size) even if the telescope magnifies.